# Can there be a bracketed locked after locked questions like with on hold and closed questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While a question that's **on hold** or **closed** is indicated in brackets [in the general list of questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions), a question that's **locked** isn't. (For example, at the time of this writing, [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122574/8610).)

Is there a reason *not* to display a bracketed **locked** after a locked question in the general list of questions? If there is *no* reason, would it be possible—so folks don't get their hopes up about answering such questions—to indicate in the general list of questions also that a question is **locked**?

Comment: As a nuance, permanent locks (that are meant to be permanent, rather than merely manually unlocked) usually complement a [closed]. I don't think that negates or affects the feature-request, but may shed light on the status quo.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Because I'm now curious, besides *closed* and *on hold*, another bracketed question status is *duplicate.* Are there other, still rarer ones?

Comment: Hm… not that I can think of. All these bracketed statuses are the different variations of the closed status, with the differences just cosmetic/informative of the variant.

Comment: Duplicate on main meta: [Could we please get some UI differentiation for locked posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51498/323179) (and more specifically [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73519/323179)).

Comment: @Laurel Thank you, but maybe it's time to revisit this topic after nearly a decade?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are interested in this feature (other than quality of life)? If you are searching through questions just put the string "locked:no" and it will exclude any locked questions in the query (I don't know why that isn't included in the Advanced Search Tips section, but it works).

Comment: @DavidCoffron It's merely a quality of life issue. In the same way that a user who clicks on a migrated, duplicated, or closed question knows that the question is out-of-the-ordinary beforehand, it just seems courteous to alert the user that a question's also locked.